# combining row an column marginal distributions to sample a specific cell values

Tags: sampling, matrix, marginal-distribution

It must be the time here (after midnight) as I have a blackout.

I have a matrix with some missing values I want to fill. for a certain cell,
I know that the marginal row probability has mean r (more specifically, the marginal row probability follows the beta distribution with some parameters I know). the marginal column distribution of that cell has mean c (it follows a beta distribution with different known parameters)

what value should I "plug" in that cells (or which probability to sample from, in filling that value?)

EDIT: some further explanations...
The matrix consists values that are sampled from some distribution, with missing values in a few cell. The matrix is large enough so I can estimate the parameters of a the row marginal distribution and column marginal distribution and want to use that information to fill "realistic" values in the blank cell.

for some realistic context: I measure the probability of something to happen, under the combination of two factors. so the rows and columns represent the levels of those factors, and the values in the cells are the empirical measured probabilities of the event. I made many measurements on many combinations of the factors, but not all, and want to estimate the probabilities for the unmeasured combinations.

Comment: Given that a cell of a matrix is a *single number,* could you explain what you mean by "marginal row probability" and "marginal column distribution"?

Comment: my matrix is a random sampling from some distribution.  with some missing values. as the matrix is large I can estimate the marginal row and column distributions. and I want to use that information to fill the blanks. Does this clarify the situation?

Comment: It helps--but please make sure that you edit your post to include that information.  Comments are transient and often unread, so the post needs to be understood by itself.  You might consider explaining exactly *how* the matrix represents a sample from a distribution.